# Dell XPS 9550 screen flickers every minute or so

Tags: laptop-display, xps

Xps 9550 UltraHD
Windows 10

Why does my 15-inch UltraHD screen flicker every now and then? 
I checked the setting and it is 60Hz refresh.  I felt that this problem started after auto software updates... bios was refreshed and Windows 10 had updates.

I tried recovery to previous Restore point...before the bios was refreshed but I am still getting these flickers.  The flickers are not constant at 1 minute intervals...

Is there another setting somewhere that I should look?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a known bios bug with the Xps 9550. Dell is constantly is saying a fix is in the works but that was a while ago, Untill today still no fix. The only fix for this is to downgrade your bios to 1.2 or 1.19.

Edit:
Here is the 1.20 file http://www.dell.com/support/home/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/drivers/DriversDetails?productCode=xps-15-9550-laptop&driverId=KTR76